Keep row count of zero when conditionally counting in data.table's .N
Similar questions at here and here but these fail to address including condition or requires separating the zero count at the start and merging them back in.
library(data.table)   
as.data.table(iris)[Sepal.Length > 6, .(n=.N), .(Species)]

returns
      Species     n
       <fctr> <int>
1: versicolor    20
2:  virginica    41

but suppose I want to include setota 0.
This can be achieved using dplyr through
iris %>%
  group_by(Species, .drop=FALSE) %>%
  filter(Sepal.Length > 6) %>%
  summarize(n = n())

  Species        n
  <fct>      <int>
1 setosa         0
2 versicolor    20
3 virginica     41

What would be a proper way to do it in data.table?
Thank you.

See here though it's from 2013 and while it's a slight improvement on those you linked, not very elegant. I'm not aware of any update to this in data.table in recent years but I might have missed it.

@SamR
thank you. Using your link's Uwe's answer, as.data.table(iris)[Sepal.Length > 6][.(Species = levels(Species)), on = .(Species), .N, by = .EACHI] seems to do the trick without requiring merging. I would happily mark yours as solved if you place it as an answer.

You can do the calculation in [i, j, ], e.g.
as.data.table(iris)[, .(n = sum(Sepal.Length > 6)), by = Species]
      Species     n
       <fctr> <int>
1:     setosa     0
2: versicolor    20
3:  virginica    41


perhaps I was too locked in a thought of using .N.  Clean and elegant.

An approach based on .N. You can group the whole dataset by Species; and for each species, you count the number of rows where Sepal.Length is greater than 6.
  dt[, .SD[Sepal.Length>6, .N], Species]

      Species    V1
       <fctr> <int>
1:     setosa     0
2: versicolor    20
3:  virginica    41

